# Symfony debug toolbar working intermittently

Tags: symfony1

I am using SF 1.3.2 with Propel ORM on Ubuntu 9.10

Recently, my debug toolbar has been working intermittently, sometimes, for no apparent reason, clicking it does not display/hide the debugging windows, forcing me to resort to looking directly at the log files.

AFAIK, nothing has changed on my machine. Is this a know bug, are there work arounds/fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS. Looks like they ruin web debug toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar is built with JavaScript, so if there was a fatal JavaScript error on the page somewhere (or in your code), it might stop the debug bar from functioning properly.

Use the Firebug addon for Firefox to find any JavaScript issues.